# Algorithm name for sorting of numbers into ascending groups

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

Assume there is a queue like this (the lines are only for clarity. They don't represent anything):

```
[1,1,1,
2,2,2,
3,3,
4,
5]
```

I want to sort it into this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,
1,2,3,
1,2]
```

Is there an algorithm that solves this and if so, how is it called?

Comment: What if you had input like `1,1,3,3` ?

Comment: @DanielA.White That's not an algorithm.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen result should then be [1,3,1,3]

Comment: So basically whatever algorithm there may be (or not be) would work by first generating the "best" increasing sequence from numbers in the input, then having generated that and removed the participating numbers from the input, continue to generate the "best" increasing sequence and removing the participating numbers from the input until the input is empty?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If I understand your description correctly, that should make the desired result. This "reorder" would happen every time new number is pushed so it may be quite slow for big arrays. The purpose of this question was to discover if there are already some smart solutions to this that I may not know about. Result for 1,3,4,5 would be as it is: 1,3,4,5.

Comment: What do you mean by "pushed"? Do you mean that you need an algorithm/implementation that is able to quickly output the results in the fact of changing input? Meaning that the original input is 1,2,3,4,5, and then someone adds another 2, you need the inpaut to "quickly" re-analyze the situation to see if that 2 can be added to an existing part of the solution or warrants a new sequent in the output? It is *very* different having to take an input and producing an output, and handling changes to the input in real time. Please clarify what you need here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There isn't any need to take the approach of counting occurrences described in [the levis501s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926452/algorithm-name-for-sorting-of-numbers-into-ascending-groups/32926545#32926545) although it could well be argued that his code is more concise or more appropriate for Python environments.

You can solve this by repeating a loop until all the original elements are sorted and in that loop iterating through the list to find the smallest number that is greater than the last found number and popping it onto a result stack for that iteration and then terminating the inner loop when there aren't any larger numbers.

If you wanted to name the algorithm it to use, it could be a histogram sort variant or perhaps a bucket sort variant ... if you dug into parallel sorting algorithms, you may find something that more closely describes your problem.

Here's a Perl implementation:

```
my @a = reverse(qw/ 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5/); ## Reverse order allows us to trim the array without messing up indexes
print qq{Source array = } . join(',',@a) . "\n";
my @bucket = ();
while ($#a >= 0)
{
  my @bucket = ();            ## Start a new bucket
  for (my $i=$#a; $i>=0; $i--)
  {
    if ($#bucket == -1 &&  $a[$i]>0 || $bucket[$#bucket] < $a[$i])
    {
        push @bucket, $a[$i];
        splice @a, $i, 1; ## Remove the element from the source data
    }
  }
  print join(',', @bucket) . "\n"; ## Display the constructed bucket list
}
```

Or using an approach similar to levis501, again in Perl:

```
my @a = (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5);

my $hist = {};
foreach my $i (@a)
{
  $hist->{$i}++;
}

while (scalar(%$hist)> 0)
{
  foreach my $el (sort keys %$hist)
  {
    $hist->{$el}--;
    print qq{$el};
    delete $hist->{$el} if $hist->{$el}<1;
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think this is the closest answer I'll probably get. It's not for a homework, it's for a production app but I though explaining the details may not be relevant. I'll accept this as correct (that this algorithm doesn't exists).

Comment: have updated with a couple of implementations - if you have a different language preference let me know and I'll have a crack

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing in Python, check out the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class which turns a list into a type of histogram:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [1, 1, 1,
     2, 2, 2,
     3, 3,
     4,
     5]
c = Counter(l)
result = []
for i in range(max(c.values())):
  result += [k for k,v in c.items() if v > i]
print(result)
```

Comment: Basically, you can count the number of occurrences of each data item, and  build the result by concatenating lists of increasing number of occurrences.  I've never heard of a specific name for this, however.  "Histogram" is the closest I know, though not exact.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [levis501s'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926452/algorithm-name-for-sorting-of-numbers-into-ascending-groups/32926545#32926545), but this seems simpler (or at least different). As with his answer, this uses Python although similar functionality can be implemented without too much effort in other high-level languages.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
while c:
    run = list(c)
    run.sort()
    for e in run:
        print(e)
        c[e] -= 1
        if c[e] == 0:
            del c[e]
```